# Chrome extension get access to not active tab dom by staying in the current tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

> Current tab

```
http://dumbo.com
```

> contentScript.js

I am in a current tab and i send message to `background.js` to open new tab for `blabla.com`

```
 const link = "https://blabla.com"
 chrome.runtime.sendMessage(
    {
      payload: {
        link: link,
      },
    },
    (response) => {
      console.log(response.message);
    }
  );
```

> background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    const link = request.payload.link;
    const message = `Opening ${link} in seperate tab`;

    // here i open new tab `blabla.com` and not sure how to get access to `blabla.com` dom here ????
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: link, active: false }, (tab) => {});

    // Send a response message
    sendResponse({
      message,
    });
});
```

Now i want to extract data from tab `blabla.com` without losing context of tab `dumbo.com` ? Not sure if this is possible ?

Comment: Each tab has its own instance of the matching content scripts so you can't lose the context as long as the original page stays open.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks. Is `brandground.js` and `popup.js` are single instance or each tab has it own instance of each ?

Comment: Background script is single (it runs in a hidden background page). Each *visible* popup is a separate instance, the popup runs each time when shown and terminates when hidden.

Comment: @wOxxOm I see. Thanks for the clarification. Can you please lead me to some example of `opening a tab from contentScript, wait for processing that tab, and than close the tab and return back to initial tab ?